# Why does "random.choices" return always the same element when passing a list "cum_weights" of decreasing values?

Tags: python, random

I don't understand the `cum_weights` parameter of `random.choices`.

I read that it is:

Weight of previous element + own weight
[10, 5, 1] → [10, 15, 16]

So as I understand it, the probability of `"cherry"` is 16 and it is the highest. So why is `"apple"` more repetitive as a result?

```
import random

mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(random.choices(mylist, cum_weights=[10, 5, 1], k=9))
```

outputs:

```
['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
```

Comment: It seems like you wanted to pass `weights`, not `cum_weights`.

Comment: `cum_weights` should be increasing.  It doesn't make sense if it isn't.  Just use `weights` if it's easier, it's internally converted to `cum_weights` inside `random.choices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have relative weights, the cumulative weights look like the sum of those values:

Your cum_weights should be: `[10, 15, 16]`

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(random.choices(mylist, cum_weights=[10, 15, 16], k=14))
```

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana']
```

Comment: Now i got that, the documentation is not su much clear in this respect hats of to you . you are the true community helper .

Answer (score 1):

The `cum_weights` parameter is not further cummulated. You can look at the implementation of the function here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py#L473
And have a look this line https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py#L505
Where the output is being generated. In the `bisect` method it tries to identify the position of the index `random()*total` in the array `cum_weights`. In your case `cum_weights` is `[10, 5, 1]`. And look at this line https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/random.py#L500 to understand how `total` is computed.
`total = cum_weights[-1] +0.0`
That means your `total` is always `1.0` as the last value of `cum_weights` is 1. So, you are always getting the first index i.e. 0 in your population. So your output will contain all 'apple'. Even if you run the algorithm thousand times you will get only `apple` in our output list with your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Saying `weights=[10,5,1]` is the same as saying `cum_weights=[10,15,16]`.  The `cum_weights` values must be in increasing order for it to make sense.  What you provided would confuse things.  `choice` is going to use the maximum value as its random range, so in your case it's going to choose a number from 0 to 9, and because your first 10 values are "apple", it's always going to choose "apple".

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the relative weight and cumulative weight.
The `cum_weights=[10, 5, 1]` parameter in the random choices is the cumulative weight itself, it doesn't cumulate further.